# IntelPin, Ins_Insertcall?

Tags: c++, pintool

please help me with Intel Pin:
I print each instruction to the console and I want to insert +++++ after it using Ins_Insertcall:

```
VOID CpuidCalled(const CONTEXT* ctxt)
{
std::cerr << "+++++" << std::endl;
}

std::cerr << INS_Disassemble(ins) << std::endl;
INS_InsertCall(
ins,
IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)CpuidCalled,
IARG_CONTEXT,
IARG_END
);
```

Output:

```
mov esp, esi
pop ebx
pop edi
pop esi
pop ebp
ret 0x10
+++++
+++++
+++++
+++++
+++++
+++++
mov byte ptr [ebp-0x19], al
mov dword ptr [ebp-0x4], 0xfffffffe
mov dword ptr [ebp-0x24], 0x0
call 0x779fdd6d
+++++
+++++
+++++
+++++
```

why so and how can it be fixed? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

that's because you are printing disassembly in instrumentation routine and "+++++" in analysis routine.

PIN has theoretically been divided into two routines:

1. instrumentation - where you define your instrumentation points - happens when instruction is jitted
2. analysis - where you execute actual instrumentation code - happens when instruction is executed

Refer following slides for quick overview:

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/cgo2013-256675.pdf

so, what you should do? - depends on your preference - either print both disassembly and "+++++" in analysis routine - i.e. inside function CpuidCalled (which makes more sense), or print both in instrumentation routine (which would not make much sense as you want to observe the executed instructions).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how to call CpuidCalled a function by analogy with INS_Disassemble(ins)? I need to output:
mov esp, esi
EAX= ... , IP=...

Comment: send it like `new string(INS_Disassemble(ins))` as an argument in the instrumentation function

Comment: #include "pin.H"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
VOID DisplayInstruction(ADDRINT instructionAddress,string assemblyCode){
 cout<<std::hex<<instructionAddress<<":"<<std::dec<<assemblyCode<<"\n";}

VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
{       
 INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)DisplayInstruction,
    IARG_INST_PTR, IARG_REG_VALUE,new string(INS_Assemble(ins)), IARG_END);
}
error new string: type specifier required,
may be new std:string?

Comment: `IARG_PTR, new string(INS_Disassemble(ins)),`

Comment: INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)DisplayInstruction,
        IARG_INST_PTR, IARG_PTR, new string(INS_Disassemble(ins)), IARG_END);, but error again:type specifier required

Comment: add using namespace std... but intel pin crashes on startup

Comment: i can't comment about your code and syntax errors, you have to experiment with it